# C# Delegate value does not fall within the expected range error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, delegates, event-handling

this is a question programming C# within Unity game engine, but it might be C# delegate expert without Unity experience could know what I'm doing wrong? (I did post on Unity forum already).

I am trying to pass an arbitrary function to be called inside a fixed function, which itself is called using delegate keyword through the `AddListener` function of `InputField.onEndEdit` event. I am new to delegates, but as I understand, I need to create a new delegate to do this, and I'm getting bit tangled up, having read a few delegate articles still stuck. Currently, code compiles but get `ArgumentException` error. Unfortunately, with full stack trace on in Unity Editor, this is all the stack trace I get:

```
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
CharacterController3D..ctor () (at Assets/Entities/DungeonCell/Priest/CharacterController3D.cs:95)
```

Where the script name is `CharacterController3D.cs`. Line 95 constructor in this class, generating this error is:

`Del marySuccess = question.MarySuccess;`

End Objective: When player inputs an answer to an arbitrary question posed when player triggers it in game, the ProcessAnswer function will call a customised function processing correct answer to each question, ie each question will have different function dealing with a correct answer response. Likewise, the ProcessAnswer function will call different custom function for that question if player gives wrong answer and so on.

Below is the ProcessAnswer function, with arbitrary delegate passed to it `delegate1`, which in following code block runs when correct answer is given:

```
 private void ProcessAnswer (InputField input, string answer, float clockStart, Del delegate1)
 {
     if (String.Equals(answer, input.text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) // trim trailing spaces, accept any case in letters typed

     {
         countdownTimer.enabled = false; // stops timer
         float timePoints = Mathf.Round(2000/(clockStart - countdownTimer.TimeStoppedTenthsSecond()));
         delegate1();
     }
     else ....
```

Above function is called in same script by:

```
 string answer = "grace";
 clockStart = 90f;
 inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate { ProcessAnswer(inputField, answer, clockStart, marySuccess); });
```

where `marySuccess` is the delegate parameter in this case, defined by:

```
 private delegate void Del();
 Del marySuccess = question.MarySuccess;
```

Still in this same script, `question` here is declared as a static instance of a separate component script on same object. I understood have to make it static for the delegate to reference it, didn't work as non-static anyway:

```
 private static Questions question;
```

and initialised in the Awake method, all in same script:

```
 question = this.GetComponent<Questions>();
```

**EDIT**
As comments, apology for missing the MarySuccess() method code itself, which has same signature as the delegate declaration (no parameters, returns void):

```
public void MarySuccess()
    {
        string phrase1 = "a";
        string phrase2 = "b";
        string phrase3 = "c";
        string phrase4 = "d";

        thoughtText.color = new Color(0.55f, 0f, 0.03f); // now matches (141,0,8) colour of input text, was Color.red;

        thoughtText.fontSize = 22;
        StartCoroutine(player.FillThoughtBox(phrase1, 3, phrase2, 3, phrase3, 5, phrase4));
        playerInputPanel.SetActive(false);

        player.Invoke("MaryHailed", 10f);
        Invoke("HideThoughtPanel", 22f);
    }

    // use Invoke() with desired delay, so that player can start moving and have more time to read the words before it disappears
    private void HideThoughtPanel()
    {
        thoughtButtonPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
```

**EDIT2**

I checked even with `public void MarySuccess () {}` empty, still gives same exception error.

Any suggestions very grateful, thanks!

Comment: `ctor` is just the shorthand for constructor. With regard to your ArgumentException, look at its stack trace. It tells you the sequence of method calls that leads to the exception. `Del marySuccess = question.MarySuccess;` could possibly only cause an ArgumentException if `question.MarySuccess` is a property whose getter has a side-effect (i.e., in some form or shape it directly or indirectly does more than just simply returning the property value)

Comment: thanks @elgonzo, @dymanoid, @SaturnusK1, have included full code for the `MarySuccess()` method now, and not very helpful stack trace. I don't know much about side-effects, not clear in this delegate case what the getter would refer to.

Comment: Thanks @dymanoid, line 95 constructor is `Del marySuccess = question.MarySuccess;` as mentioned top of question, should have made clearer there am editing, all the code at top is from this `CharacterController3D` class. I tried deleting all code inside MarySuccess() method ie just `public void MarySuccess() {}`, and still gives same exception error. I then tried changing Questions class to inherit from ScriptableObject not the Unity Monobehaviour class, breaks it in other way, but error still there from this constructor, same line. Will try more print to console and these tools thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this long time ago now, but in case anyone else reads, the problem was using private scope for the delegate function. From above question, code I had was:

```
 private delegate void Del();
 Del marySuccess = question.MarySuccess;
```

which generated the error in 2nd line. It should be:

```
public delegate void Del();
```

because `MarySuccess()` method is public method, the delegate signature needs to match it, and also be public. Indeed, since this was calling the method in another class, the method called would have to be public to work, and therefore the delegate also needs to be public, otherwise the 'value' of `marySuccess` here does not 'fall within the expected range' ie a public delegate 'value'. I had thought that since `Del()` only used in this class, it could be private, but not appreciating that `Del()` is used as a data type, as well as a variable. It's a confusing error message I feel, since I feel that the delegate type is being assigned a reference not a value, but very welcome if someone more experienced can correct any errors in detail of this analysis..

Answer (score 0):

I got the very same exception in a very similar case.  In my case it turned out that the expression `question.MarySuccess` (fetching a delegate) raises this particularly unexpected error if `question` is null.  That's the difference between

```
Del x = question.MarySuccess;
```

and

```
Del x = () => question.MarySuccess();
```

The second version will work even if `question` is null, and raise a `NullReferenceException` only later and only if `x` is actually called.